# SQL Server : List of users who have queried a particular table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Does anyone have a query that would show you a history of who performed a query against a specific table and when?

Comment: The answer greatly depends on the DBMS you use. Oracle, Postgres, MySQL,..?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/cc280386.aspx

Comment: My reaction to "SQL 2010" is [similar to this](http://dbareactions.com/post/100255292524/when-the-client-says-theyre-upgrading-to-sql)

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2010** - we have 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014 - pick the one you're really using ...

Comment: My bad, it is 2008 R2

Comment: Server Auditing can be used to accomplish this like @TI said, but you can only query changes made while auditing is enabled.  If you're looking to find out what has already happened, there's no option in SQL Server.  That metadata is not created automatically.